# How return two functions in TypeScript as result?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following function:

```
public exist(index: number, type: string): boolean {
    return this.forms.filter(form => form.index == index + 1 && form.type == type).length > 0;
  }
```

This function returns true/false if element exists in array of objects.

How to return two functions instead boolean:`_exist() {},` and `form()` to use this like:

```
const e = this.exist(1, 'formLogin');
if (e._exist()) {
    console.log(e.form());
}
```

It means if `this.forms.filter` return true I can get access to `e.form()`

I think I need to use closure

I tried to do this:

```
public exist(index: number, type: string) {

    const lookForm = this.forms.filter(form => form.index == index + 1 && form.type == type);
    const lookFormExist = form.length > 0;

    function form() {
       return lookForm.shift();
    }

    return lookFormExist;
  }
```

Comment: I suppose it should be function in function, like closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return an object with the functions on it.

Separately: `filter(...).length > 0` is never the right way to just *check for* the presence of something in an array. Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if it's an `===` check, or [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) if you need to use a callback as in your case. But in this case, it seems like you want to use the form, in which case you'd use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
public exist(index: number, type: string): ExistResult {
  const form = this.forms.find(form => form.index == index + 1 && form.type == type);
  return {_exist() { return !!form; }, form() { return form; }} as ExistResult;
}
```

...where `ExistResult` is a type you'd define for this.

**However, I wouldn't do that.** I'd just return the result of `find`, and either use the form, or branch if the result was falsy. I'd probably also change the name of the function.

```
public findForm(index: number, type: string): Form {
  return this.forms.find(form => form.index == index + 1 && form.type == type);
}
```

then

```
const form : Form = this.findForm(1, 'formLogin');
if (form) {
    console.log(form);
}
```

Comment: `ExistResult` is an interface you created?  Might want to add the code

Comment: @jcalz - I leave it as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: This like unclear for me: `return {_exist() { return !!form; }, form() { return form; }} as ExistResult;`

Comment: @OPV - What about it? The functions in the answer are also closures. But the functions in the answer are accessible from the caller, whereas your `form` function is entirely private, can't be called from the outside. Also, again, there's just no need at all for that temporary array you're creating, nor for the `shift` call.

Comment: @OPV - That's an object initializer containing two methods.